# SELECT, format rows with different columns into a single row that share an ID

Tags: select, join, oracle11g, case

I'm trying to format one `SELECT` statement so that it outputs a resultset with combined values over a few columns.

I have a resultset like this:

```
ID   VID    PID   VALUE

1    x      1     a
2    y      1     A
3    y      2     B
4    x      2     b
5    y      3     C
6    x      3     c
7    x      4     d
8    y      4     D
9    x      5     e
10   y      5     E
```

Can I format one `SELECT` statement to effectively join the values with duplicate `PID`s into a single row? I'm only really interested in `PID` and `VALUE`, e.g.

```
PID   VALUE1   VALUE2

1     a        A
2     b        B   
3     c        C
4     d        D
5     e        E
```

Otherwise, should I be using actual `JOIN`s with queries acting on the same table?

I tried to use `CASE` but can get up to a resultset like this:

```
ID   VID    PID   VALUE1   VALUE2

1    x      1     a        NULL
2    y      1     NULL     A
3    y      2     NULL     B
4    x      2     b        NULL
5    y      3     NULL     C
6    x      3     c        NULL
7    x      4     d        NULL
8    y      4     NULL     D
9    x      5     e        NULL
10   y      5     NULL     E
```

The query I'm using looks somewhat like this.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    VID,
    PID,
    CASE WHEN VID = 'x' THEN VALUE END VALUE1,
    CASE WHEN VID = 'y' THEN VALUE END VALUE2
FROM BIGTABLE
WHERE PID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND VID IN ('x', 'y')
```

There's a lot of values of `PID` and `VID` that aren't just 1-5 and x & y so I'm selecting them that way from the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? It's called "conditional aggregation."

```
with
     resultset ( id, vid, pid, value ) as (
       select  1, 'x', 1, 'a' from dual union all
       select  2, 'y', 1, 'A' from dual union all
       select  3, 'y', 2, 'B' from dual union all
       select  4, 'x', 2, 'b' from dual union all
       select  5, 'y', 3, 'C' from dual union all
       select  6, 'x', 3, 'c' from dual union all
       select  7, 'x', 4, 'd' from dual union all
       select  8, 'y', 4, 'D' from dual union all
       select  9, 'x', 5, 'e' from dual union all
       select 10, 'y', 5, 'E' from dual
     )
-- End of simulated resultset (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line.
select   pid,
         min(case when vid = 'x' then value end) as value1,
         min(case when vid = 'y' then value end) as value2
from     resultset
--  WHERE conditions, if any are needed - as in your attempt
group by pid
order by pid
;

PID VALUE1 VALUE2
--- ------ ------
  1 a      A     
  2 b      B     
  3 c      C     
  4 d      D     
  5 e      E
```

Comment: So, I have to use an analytic/aggregate function for the `GROUP BY` clause to work in these cases? If I only try `CASE`s I'll get an `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: @Eriol - you want only one row per `PID`, so you do want to aggregate (`GROUP BY`). If you aggregate, you MUST use aggregate functions (like `MIN` or `MAX` or `SUM`) on the columns that are not "grouped by". In conditional aggregation, as shown here, some values will be `NULL`, and they will be ignored by aggregate functions like `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`. That's the difference between your solution and mine. Starting in Oracle 11.1 you can use the `PIVOT` operator, which is also an aggregation (but the syntax does not use the `GROUP BY` clause).